For loop doesn´t end despite start in i=0
I have to do an internship for the University and I am having a problem. I have to indicate on the screen two restaurants that we have entered. To do this, they ask me to perform an action in which we enter the data manually and save it (readRestaurant action) and then we must display the data entered in the previous action on the screen (showRestaurant).
The fact is that when I create both loops for with the corresponding action, when I run the program and perform the first loop for, it asks me for the data of both restaurants and when I enter the second, it starts the loop for again, not going to the next loop to display the entered data on the screen. I leave the code below in case you can find the error that causes the first loop to not close.
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//Definimos las constantes con las que vamos a trabajar
#define MAX_RESTAURANTES 2
//introducimos la estructura con la que vamos a trabajar en el programa
typedef struct {
    char nombre[12]; //los caracteres máximos serán 12
    float importe; // importe del menu que puede contener decimales
    int estrellas; // numero de estrellas michelin que puede ser 0
} tRestaurante;
//Implementamos las acciones y funciones para que se usen en nuestro programa

void readRestaurante (tRestaurante *restaurante);
void mostrarRestaurante (tRestaurante restaurante);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    tRestaurante Restaurante[MAX_RESTAURANTES];

    printf("INPUT\n");

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_RESTAURANTES; i++) {
        printf("RESTAURANT %i\n", i);
        readRestaurante(&Restaurante[i]);
    }

    printf("OUTPUT\n");
    printf("THE BEST RESTAURANT IS:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_RESTAURANTES; i++) {
        mostrarRestaurante(Restaurante[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}


//Debemos introducir una acción para leer los datos de los restaurantes

void readRestaurante (tRestaurante *restaurante) {
    printf("NAME?\n");
    scanf("%s", restaurante->nombre);
    printf("PRICE MENU?\n");
    scanf("%f", &restaurante->importe);
    printf("MICHELIN STARS\n");
    scanf("%i", &restaurante->estrellas);
}

void mostrarRestaurante (tRestaurante restaurante) {
    printf("NAME: %s\n", restaurante.nombre);
    printf("PRICE MENU: %.2f\n", restaurante.importe);
    printf("MICHELIN STARS: %i\n", restaurante.estrellas);
}

I want to move to the next for loop, the one that performs the show restaurant action.

for (i=1; i<=MAX_RESTAURANTES; i++) ==> for (i=0; i< MAX_RESTAURANTES; i++). Arrays start with index 0.

Anyone know of a good canonical dupe for "arrays are zero indexed in C"?

@Lundin Why do array indices start at zero in C?

@Filburt Good enough! I'll add that one to the C wiki link collection.

@Nicolas Please adopt proper indentation and consistent formatting for your code.
